# How do I make a div element editable (like a textarea when I click it)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"> 
    </head> 
<body> 
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 

        </style> 

        <!--<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;background:blue;"></div>-->

        <div class=b style="width: 200px; height: 200px;background:pink;position:absolute;left:500px;top:100px;"></div>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 

        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Let's work through it.

You can't make a div editable. There's no such thing as an editable div, at least for now. So the problem is finding out what to use for editing instead. A textarea works perfectly. So the idea is to somehow get a textarea where the div currently sits.

The question is how and from where do we get the textarea. There are various ways, but one of them is to dynamically create a textarea on the fly:

```
var editableText = $("<textarea />");
```

and replace it with the div:

```
$("#myDiv").replaceWith(editableText);
```

The textarea is in place now. But it is empty and we have just replaced the div and lost everything. So we need to preserve the text of the div somehow. One way is to copy the text/html inside the div before replacing it:

```
var divHtml = $("#myDiv").html(); // or text(), whatever suits.
```

Once we have the html from the div, we can populate the textarea and safely replace the div with the textarea. And set the focus inside the textarea as the user might want to start editing. Combining all the work upto this point, we get:

```
// save the html within the div
var divHtml = $("#myDiv").html();
// create a dynamic textarea
var editableText = $("<textarea />");
// fill the textarea with the div's text
editableText.val(divHtml);
// replace the div with the textarea
$("#myDiv").replaceWith(editableText);
// editableText.focus();
```

It's functional but nothing happens when a user clicks a div because we didn't setup any events. Let's wire up the events. When the user clicks any div `$("div").click(..)`, we create a click handler, and do all of the above.

```
$("div").click(function() {
    var divHtml = $(this).html(); // notice "this" instead of a specific #myDiv
    var editableText = $("<textarea />");
    editableText.val(divHtml);
    $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus();
});
```

This is good, but we'd want a way to get our div back when a user clicks out or leaves the textarea. There is a `blur` event for form controls that is triggered when a user leaves the control. That can be used to detect when a user leaves the textarea, and replace back the  div. We do the exact reverse this time. Preserve the value of textarea, create a dynamic div, set it's html, and replace out the textarea.

```
$(editableText).blur(function() {
    // Preserve the value of textarea
    var html = $(this).val();
    // create a dynamic div
    var viewableText = $("<div>");
    // set it's html 
    viewableText.html(html);
    // replace out the textarea
    $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
});
```

Everything is great, except that this new div will no longer convert into a textarea on click. This is a newly created div, and we'll have to setup the `click` event again. We already have the entire code, but better than repeating it twice, it's better to make a function out of it.

```
function divClicked() {
    var divHtml = $(this).html();
    var editableText = $("<textarea />");
    editableText.val(divHtml);
    $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus();
    // setup the blur event for this new textarea
    editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}
```

Since the whole operation is two-way reversible, we'll need to do the same for the textarea. Let's convert that into a function too.

```
function editableTextBlurred() {
    var html = $(this).val();
    var viewableText = $("<div>");
    viewableText.html(html);
    $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
    // setup the click event for this new div
    $(viewableText).click(divClicked);
}
```

---

Wiring up everything together, we have 2 functions, `divClicked`, `editableTextBlurred` and the line below triggers everything:

```
$("div").click(divClicked);
```

Checkout this code at http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/. This is not the best way of writing editable divs by any means, but just one way to start and approach the solution step by step. Honestly I have learnt just as much as you in writing this long piece. Signing off, adios!

Comment: There are various other existing in-place editor plugins for jQuery listed in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery. `Editable` and `Jeditable` as Sarfaraz already mentioned are some of the good ones, but I don't know what has in-place editing got anything to do with Star Wars :D

Comment: contenteditable="true" *does* allow this capability.  IE has supported since 5.5 and HTML5 provides for this

Comment: Why we need to follow all these? Can't we make div editable using attribute contenteditable="true". I have used it many times and never faced any problems.

Comment: I made a jquery plugin out of your idea: [jquery-html-editable](https://github.com/zevero/jquery-html-editable)

Comment: Nice explanation, but I have to downvote this because it's based on a premise that's no longer true: "You can't make a div editable." As others have already mentioned you _can_ make a div editable using [contenteditable="true"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content). The answer needs to be updated to include that option. (This approach is an awful lot of unnecessary effort when there's already an easy option.)

Answer (score 91):

To make a `<div>` (or any element for that matter) editable you can use the `contenteditable` HTML attribute.

For example:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Anything inside this div will be editable!</div>
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Comment: The div no longer behaves like normal div when contenteditable="true" in respect to links which become inactive.

Comment: The method for having links remain active is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059211/how-to-make-clickable-anchor-in-contenteditable-div

Answer (score 11):

Use `contenteditable="true"` attributes for the division.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answer of Anurag I wrote a small jquery plugin:

https://github.com/zevero/jquery-html-editable

which allows you to make all 'div.myDiv' elements editable:

```
$('body').html_editable('div.myDiv');
```

Answer (score 4):

`contenteditable` has some grave defects. The most damning in my view, is cross browser incompatability on Enter use. See this [article](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/rich-html-editing-in-the-browser-part-1/) for a description. In Firefox clicking Enter for a carriage return creates a new paragraph, effectively double spacing every line that isn't long enough to wrap. Very ugly.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. This should be a comment instead.

Answer (score 4):

For those looking for an `on()` version, this is based on Anurag's answer.

If, for some reason, you wanted to take the click event off the editable text input (eg for viewing editable and non editable versions of content), you could later apply `$(document).off("click", ".editable_text");`.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".editable_text", function() {
  var original_text = $(this).text();
  var new_input = $("<input class=\"text_editor\"/>");
  new_input.val(original_text);
  $(this).replaceWith(new_input);
  new_input.focus();
});

$(document).on("blur", ".text_editor", function() {
  var new_input = $(this).val();
  var updated_text = $("<span class=\"editable_text\">");
  updated_text.text(new_input);
  $(this).replaceWith(updated_text);
});
```

```css
.text_editor {
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span class="editable_text">Here is my original text.</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <div id="myP">This is a paragraph. Click the button to make me editable.</div>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myP").contentEditable = true;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The p element above is now editable. Try to change its text.";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    this.contentEditable = 'true';
});
```

Working example at https://jsfiddle.net/pgdqhacj/2/. The only downside is that you have to double click to edit the text, not single click.