# How to make a div contenteditable and draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="d">
<span>Text to edit</span>
</div>

$("#d").draggable();
```

I can only drag this div but how can i edit it (like on doubleclick editable property become active and on click dragging become active)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$("#d").draggable()
  .click(function() {
    $(this).draggable({ disabled: false });
}).dblclick(function() {
    $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });
});
​​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UH9UE/1)

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#d")
.draggable()
.click(function(){
    if ( $(this).is('.ui-draggable-dragging') ) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).draggable( "option", "disabled", true );
    $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
})
.blur(function(){
    $(this).draggable( 'option', 'disabled', false);
    $(this).attr('contenteditable','false');
});
```

This is the DEMO  :  http://jsfiddle.net/UH9UE/222/.

Comment: It is not working when first time click on area.anything missing?

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to pass the .draggable({ handle: "handleDiv" }) which allows you to keep draggable on all the time as well as allowing contenteditable editing. Just make your draggable div with two divs inside: the handle, and your contenteditable div.

[API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-handle)

Answer (score 1):

I find the follow behaviour much more intuitiv and smoothly (no double click needed).

**Version 1** (best)
http://jsfiddle.net/k1d9ftyu/

```js
d.onmousedown = e => {
    d.contentEditable = false
}

d.ondragstart = e => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', "XXX");
}

d.ondragend = () => {
    d.contentEditable = true
}

d.onmouseup = e => {
    d.contentEditable = true
    if (document.caretRangeFromPoint)
        range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)
    else {   // firefox
        var sel = window.getSelection()
        sel.collapse(e.rangeParent, e.rangeOffset)
    }
}
```

```css
#d {
    background-color: #cfc;
    width: 200px;
}

#d[contenteditable=false] {
    cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
The green child div is contenteditable by default (as well as the parent div). The caret can run through both divs.
<div id="d" draggable=true contenteditable=true>Mousedown sets contenteditable=false, the div can be dragged. If not dragged after click, it becomes again contenteditable.</div>
The caret is positioned according to the last click.
</div>
```

**Version 2**

Similar as version 1, but uses `mouseenter` and needs a second click to position the caret correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/z8aojdg6

**Version 3**
Original version with `contenteditable=false` by default.
Due to the `focus()` call the caret is placed at the line end. Thus a second click is needed to re-position the caret (it might be improved with usage of `selection` and `range`).

```js
d.onmouseup = () => {
  d.contentEditable = true
  d.focus()
}

d.onblur = () => {
  d.contentEditable = false
}
```

```css
#d {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 130px;
    height: 90px;
}
#d:focus {
    outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="d" draggable=true contenteditable=false>
  Edit me when focussed. Drag me when inactive.</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rz28c0xe

Answer (score -1):

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="d">
<span>Text to edit</span>
</div>

$(function(){
$("#d").click(function() {
$("#d").draggable();      
});

$("#d").dblclick(function(){
see here for this functionality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it   
}); 
});
```

​