# Drag or Edit, in a single click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I have divs, which are made to textinput fields by a plugin. Also those divs are draggable.

Right now, I have reached, that if you drag the div, it gets dragged, and if you just click on it, it gets a ".focus()".

The problem is now, that if I click it once, i get a focus on it. But the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line.

What I want, is the cursor on the place, I clicked.

[image]

How can I do this with jquery? Thanks

EDIT (My JS Code):

```
$('.mydiv').click(function(){
    //actually, it does not focus on "$(this)" but on a div inside ".mydiv" which 
    //is generated by the plugin

    $(this).focus();
})
```

Comment: Can you show us the javascript that makes this magic happen? Most likely you need to not use .focus(), and instead allow the original click event to succeed.

Comment: Obviously, allowing the original click event to succeed will result in breaking your drag functionality, which is why most interfaces that do this either have a handle that you drag from, or require a double click to initiate editing.

Comment: Ye thats the problem. I want to make everything with a single click. I will edit the post with my JS code. Btw, I think it should be possible to do so. Dragging is not equal to clicking, so there should be a solution which can trigger both with a single click, based on what I do with my mouse.

Comment: dragging starts with clicking, so yes they are the same thing. you don't know if it's a drag until the mouse move happens. Then the mouse is released, which stops the drag, and completes the click event. it's far more complicated than you may think. How do you expect a user to select text to edit rather than just putting the cursor at one point? selecting text would be performing the same action as dragging.

Comment: or, more precisely, a drag is really just a very long click that involves moving the mouse. Please also include the code you are using to make it draggable.

Comment: Ye, that selecting is tricky, but I have a selected state which the div gets in when it gets clicked. Then it can be edited, and the text can be selected, as dragging is disabled in that state. If I enable the "normal" state again, by clicking on the outer space, I can again drag the element.

Comment: the dragging is a simple ".draggable()" with a few options, which don't change anything for the problem ..

Comment: so... use double click. On double click, disable dragging, then when you leave the element (click anywhere else), make it draggable again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317128/how-to-make-a-div-contenteditable-and-draggable

Answer (score 0):

You could consider listening for mouseup and mousedown instead of click, which would help you distinguish between which event the user is performing. Like, if there is a mouse down event, and the user moves the mouse before a mouseup event, then you're in "drag" mode. If there's a mouseup event, and the user is not in "drag" mode, then the user has clicked, and you can fire a focus event.

That's the approach I would take without knowing more about what you're doing.

The truth is that you have a considerably more complex interface requirement than most, meaning you're going to have to give the computer more instructions to determine what to do :)

Comment: Hey, this is what I already have so far. What I need now, is the possibility to bring the cursor to a position, where I have clicked on. (Because right now, if I click on the 9th letter for example, the cursor still moves back to the beginning)