# How can I create a simple text area that contains draggable items inside the actual text?

Tags: javascript, gwt, contenteditable

Note: this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201878/why-am-i-not-able-to-drag-the-span-but-instead-the-img) where I try to do this in pure HTML/JavaScript.

What I need is a very simple text area that allows me to place draggable items to it. Draggable in the sense that they can be moved inside the textual content - character wise. Here is an example

```
<div contenteditable="true"/>
  This is text whereas <div draggable="true">this is draggable</div> because of reasons.
</div>
```

Now clicking on `<div draggable="true">this is draggable</div>` and moving/dragging it a few characters to the right would result in:

```
<div contenteditable="true"/>
  This is text whereas beca<div draggable="true">this is draggable</div>use of reasons.
</div>
```

I found that the `RichTextArea` would basically serve my needs but it does not seem to be possible to add such draggables to the text area simply as that. I could *hack* something together I guess that would do what I want but since this is part of a key feature in my application I want something sane and reliable. I need references to those draggable objects but `RichTextArea` allows me only to set it's content via HTML Strings. Actually I need callback methods in order to determine *when* such a draggable element is for example detached from the DOM tree.

The biggest problem is actually me since I am not very experienced with GWT and/or web-development itself actually.

So the question is basically which Widget would be a good place to start with?

---

An example can be [seen here](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText). Just write some text and drag the logo [image] into the text area. You'll be able to move it's position inside the text. But like I mentioned, it is using the `RichTextArea` widget which does not seem to want me to add such elements programmatically to the text area.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317128/how-to-make-a-div-contenteditable-and-draggable

Comment: @Baz No, this is actually an example how to drag the textbox where the text is within. What I want is to be able to drag HTML elements *inside* the text area. But thank you :)

Comment: If the `RichTextArea` already handles the drag-and-drop component, all you're asking for is how to add the elements programmatically, right? `RichTextArea#setHTML(safeHtml)` with `safeHtml` representing "some text <img src=''></img>" should do it.

Comment: @Baz The problem is that I need actual references to the elements inside the textarea. I found that `RichTextArea` is inside an  `iframe` and therefore I'll not be able to keep those references since, like you mentioned, I can only add things by setting HTML strings. `RichTextArea` died for me in exactly that moment. ^^