# Why am I not able to drag the span but instead the img?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a textarea where I can add HTML elements which should be draggable on character level. This question is related [to another I am currently asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201023/how-can-i-create-a-simple-text-area-that-contains-draggable-items-inside-the-act) but that is GWT related. In order to create such a text area I am trying to understand how to do it step by step. This is what I got so far:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8y4v9ptj/4/)

JavaScript:

```
function smartdrag(e) {

    var id = e.target.getAttribute('id');

    if (id!=='plzdragme' && id !== 'plzdragmeimg') {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" ondragstart="smartdrag(event)">
    More blah
    <img src="http://lorempizza.com/80/80/2" id="plzdragmeimg" draggable="true" class="fancy-img"/>
    about 
    <span id="plzdragme" contenteditable="false" class="fancy" draggable="true">DRAGME</span>
    Sparta!
</div>
```

But for some reason I can only drag the `img`. What I actually need is to be able to drag a `span` or even better a `div`..

How can I accomplish that?

PS: Please no jQuery if possible.

Comment: So where is the code that actually drags? You're probably using some library, which one?

Comment: Guess you learn everyday! Did not know HTML5 had this functionality.

Comment: Maybe http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/ will help. (Image is draggable by default).

Comment: by default everything is 'draggable' in a contenteditable

Comment: @crl This looks a little dangerous to me :) It seems to work but it relies on text selection. I am not sure if every browser is going to be happy with this. However, this inspired me. [This one](https://jsfiddle.net/ft02zpmp/) would be simple and exactly what I need if I could move the actual element to that position and prevent the browser from creating a "naked" copy of the dragged element. Any idea if that's possible?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8y4v9ptj/8/ yes it relies on selection, but work well on chrome, on Firefox there's a bug to drag content from one contenteditable to another

Answer (score 1):

I googled around a bit to see how HTML5 dragging works, and I found that in order to get a DOM element to be draggable, you have to add the new 'draggable' attribute to it, and set it to true. The confusing part about your problem is that images and links are [draggable by default](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp)!

I wasn't really able to test this well because your script throws an error saying your function `smartdrag` does not exist.

Though I'm pretty hopeful about this possible solution as it covers your problem entirely, and comes from a trustworthy documentation.

Comment: Did you test my script in the JSFiddle? This should actually work. I know this `draggable` attribute and my problem is not making things *draggable*. My problem is placing them between characters in which they are together in a textarea. I've seen the example you're showing yet I am unable to use it for my specific task here :/