# How can I get the "drop caret position" from contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html

If one drags an element from within a `contenteditable` the browser usually shows such an "intermediate caret" as can be seen in the image below:

[image]

I am looking for a simple and reliable solution to drag an element from within a `contenteditable` by sending the elements ID as transfer data via drag and drop. Then, in the `ondrop` method I intend to place the `draggable` at the exact position where this "intermediate caret" is currently at.

The question is: Will I be able to get this information from all the browsers?

I do have a base ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft02zpmp/)) but that's far from being useful for me at the moment.

PS: I am not using jQuery or any other libraries.

Comment: i was able to craft this: https://jsfiddle.net/jkLhfzr8/, is that like what you want?

Comment: @dandavis omg this is genius! This should work on all browsers, right? This looks like chances are good that most of them are going to support this.. I am looking for a simple solution for days now and the most promising solution so far was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678451/precise-drag-and-drop-within-a-contenteditable) .. I was thinking about simply switching the elements too but I would not have been able to do that. Let me check this solution a bit but this looks like **the** answer for me! :)

Comment: @dandavis Thanks man! I think I'll go with that and please write a blog or something about this because honestly.. doing something that simple really took me a while to find out how. You could also provide your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201878/why-am-i-not-able-to-drag-the-span-but-instead-the-img) since they are closely related.

Comment: i think it would work on all DND browsers, i even avoided `elm.remove()` and used the backwards-compat `parent.removeChild` instead...

Comment: @dandavis Great! Feel free to provide an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out `document.caretRangeFromPoint` and `e.rangeParent, e.rangeOffset`.

Here is a demo
https://jsfiddle.net/znghofxt

```js
function dragElement(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
}

function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
    // edge, chrome, android
    range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)
  } else {
    // firefox
    var pos = [e.rangeParent, e.rangeOffset]
    range = document.createRange()
    range.setStart(...pos);
    range.setEnd(...pos);
  }

  range.insertNode(document.getElementById(id));
}
```

```css
.fancy {
  background-color: #123456;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
  cursor:pointer; 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fancy-img {
  cursor:pointer; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" ondrop="drop(event)">   
  More blah
  about 
  <a id="dragme" href="http://www.google.com" class="fancy" contenteditable="false" ondragstart="dragElement(event)">       
    :(
  </a>
  Sparta!
</div>
```

Comment: this is Genius. Any change there we could change drop position to end of word (avoiding it to be set int the middle of it)?