# Image onClick is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problems has 2 parts.
1. My onclick event is not working.
2. I want to change the text inside a `<div>` by providing a textbox for user to change the text inside the `<div>`.

Let me show you my code to understand this better

HTML:

```
<div class="img">
  <img src="bird-light.png" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90" onclick="changetext(this)" />
 <div id="desc" >Add a description of the image by clicking on the bird</div>
</div>
<div class="img">
  <img src="bird-dark.png" alt="Klematis" width="110" height="90" onclick="changetext(this)" />
 <div id="desc">Add a description of the image by clicking on the bird </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.img{
  width:250px;
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  height: auto;
  float:left;
  background-color:#474747;
  color:#fff;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function changetext(e){       
  alert("hi");
  txtarea = document.getElementById('desc');
}
```

[I created a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbXcw/1/)

Coming back to the **ISSUES**.

1. For some reason the JavaScript function alert is not executed which means my function is not getting triggered.
2. I want the user to be able to edit the text inside the `<div>`. What I mean is when the user clicks the image she/he should get a textbox which allows her/him to modify the text content of the `<div id="desc">`. Is it possible to do so using only JavaScript. If yes, How?

Comment: first of all id must be unique otherwise there is no easy way to get the second element with id desc in your fiddle

Comment: See this url to make div's editable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first is a non-issue because you're using JSFiddle with "wrap script in onLoad", which means the function only exists in that onload event and is unavailable to the click events.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbXcw/2/), where the code is left raw.

You can do anything with JavaScript, pretty much. Accepting user input is nothing. At it's simplest, it's just `var userinput = prompt("Type something","Default value");`, but really you want to learn some stuff like `document.createElement`, `Element.appendChild` and so on in order to create a textarea element and show it to the user.

Comment: Well. thanks. can u direct me to a resource or tutorial which can help me?

Comment: @AnaMaria [Mozilla Developers Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) Good place to learn.

Comment: I will accept this answer as i found a solution to the second part of my problem...

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is working for me, if I change the JS function like below at `onLoad`:

```
changetext = function (e) {
    alert("hi");
    var txtarea = document.getElementById('desc');
}
```

Check [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbXcw/5/)

To edit your content in your div, use `innerHTML`

```
 document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML = "content changed";
```

Comment: @AnaMaria shed some light on your question.  IDs should be uniques so change it as `class="desc"` in both.