# Edit a particular div on click using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when clicked on the div it should be displayed on textbox and it should be editable on edit button
what should be the ajax code
i have done this with php but want to do this with ajax

```
<script>
function edit()
{

            $.ajax({

            });
}
</script>
<div id="edit1" name="edit1">edit1</div>
<div id="edit2" name="edit2">edit2</div>
<div id="edit3" name="edit3">edit3</div>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<button onclick="edit(this.value)">Edit</button>
```

Comment: Why are you using ajax for that.Simple javascript will do the job.Simply show the div on your edit buton click and hide it all other times.

Comment: why there is `this.value` in onclick event?

Comment: i have done that with jacascript but want to learn that with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/4yyk3/1/)

```
    <div>when clicked on the div it should be displayed on textbox 
and it should be editable on edit button what should be the ajax code 
i have done this with php but want to do this with ajax</div>
```

JS:

```
function divClicked() {
    var divHtml = $(this).html();
    var editableText = $("<textarea />");
    editableText.val(divHtml);
    $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
    editableText.focus();
    // setup the blur event for this new textarea
    editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
    var html = $(this).val();
    var viewableText = $("<div>");
    viewableText.html(html);
    $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
    // setup the click event for this new div
    viewableText.click(divClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").click(divClicked);
});
```

Comment: I have a SO question. Ashish copied from the link below. Should we give credit do an original post? My question is in general. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it/3800567#3800567

Answer (score 1):

Try below jquery for get your div value in text box :

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

Then on the baseof that you can update your textbox using ajax call.