# How to change the opacity of a text in search box?

Tags: javascript

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ZTz.jpg

You guys have any idea,if so can you please give me an example? (I'am a novice)

Thank you

Credit goes to Krowe.

```
 // ==UserScript==
// @name       Tamper with Google Results
// @namespace  http://superuser.com/users/145045/krowe
// @version    0.1
// @description  This just modifies google results to exclude certain things.
// @match      http://*.google.com
// @match      https://*.google.com
// @copyright  2014+, KRowe
// ==/UserScript==


function GM_main () {
    window.onload = function () {
      var targ = window.location;
      if(targ && targ.href && targ.href.match('https?:\/\/www.google.com/.+#q=.+') && targ.href.search("/+-torrent/+-watch/+-download")==-1) {
        targ.href = targ.href +"+-torrent+-watch+-download";
      }
    };
}

//-- This is a standard-ish utility function:
function addJS_Node(text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D=document, scriptNode = D.createElement('script');
    if(runOnLoad) scriptNode.addEventListener("load", runOnLoad, false);
    scriptNode.type = "text/javascript";
    if(text) scriptNode.textContent = text;
    if(s_URL) scriptNode.src = s_URL;
    if(funcToRun) scriptNode.textContent = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';
    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild(scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node (null, null, GM_main);
```

Using (-) sign I can exclude unwanted results,but dont want the other users become aware of it.If someone searches Google or any other search engine this phrase(-torrent-download-watch) should be automatically and invisibly added

edit- how can I use css to add a blank white layer on top of the unwanted text and sync them  in the textarea?

For example : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAz0i.jpg

Comment: can you paste some code of things you've attempted? Its a good place to start.

Comment: `yourInput.style.color = "rgba(0, 0, 0, alpha)";`

Comment: Are you wanting to style only select words in the input field, as in your example?

Comment: @Brian I added the code. Can you please look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't change opacity for partial content.

However you can hide the input box and place a overlay div, which can mimic as a textbox, that can be then further styled with different text colors.

Take a hint from following post:

[How do I make a div element editable (like a textarea when I click it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it#2441686)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `color` to change to color of the text.

```
color:rgb(255,0,0); //red
color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5); //half opaque red.
```

The first three numbers are color, the fourth is opacity.