# Turn text element into input field type text when clicked and change back to text when clicked away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a form with fields changing on fly.

Start with simple text and when someone clicks on this text it transfers into editable text input field. When someone clicks away it turns back into non-editable text.

I gave it a go but it does not seem to work properly. Works fine on first couple of clicks but then it's loosing inputId and is mixing the buttons.

Here is the html

```
<p id="firstElement" onclick="turnTextIntoInputField('firstElement');">First Element</p>
<p id="secondElement" onclick="turnTextIntoInputField('secondElement');">Second Element</p>
```

And here is the JavaScript (using jQuery).

I am quite new in JavaScript so it may not be best quality code...

```
function turnTextIntoInputField(inputId) 
{  
    console.log(inputId);
    inputIdWithHash = "#"+inputId;
    elementValue = $(inputIdWithHash).text();
    $(inputIdWithHash).replaceWith('<input name="test" id="'+inputId+'" type="text" value="'+elementValue+'">');

    $(document).click(function(event) { 
        if(!$(event.target).closest(inputIdWithHash).length) {
            $(inputIdWithHash).replaceWith('<p id="'+inputId+'" onclick="turnTextIntoInputField(\''+inputId+'\')">'+elementValue+'</p>');
        }      

    });
}
```

Here is live example on fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7jz510hg/

I will appreciate any help as it's giving me a headache...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a div element editable (like a textarea when I click it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it)

Comment: Would one option be to have just `<input>` elements, but take away all their input styling by default, so they look like just text, and put it back when they're focused? (the CSS `:not(:focus)` may come in handy)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't need to use `onclick` in the html itself.

And here's another approach you might take:

```js
/**
  We're defining the event on the `body` element, 
  because we know the `body` is not going away.
  Second argument makes sure the callback only fires when 
  the `click` event happens only on elements marked as `data-editable`
*/
$('body').on('click', '[data-editable]', function(){
  
  var $el = $(this);
              
  var $input = $('<input/>').val( $el.text() );
  $el.replaceWith( $input );
  
  var save = function(){
    var $p = $('<p data-editable />').text( $input.val() );
    $input.replaceWith( $p );
  };
  
  /**
    We're defining the callback with `one`, because we know that
    the element will be gone just after that, and we don't want 
    any callbacks leftovers take memory. 
    Next time `p` turns into `input` this single callback 
    will be applied again.
  */
  $input.one('blur', save).focus();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p data-editable>First Element</p>
  
<p data-editable>Second Element</p>
  
<p>Not editable</p>
```

Comment: If I had votes left today I would vote you up for this. Its better than my answer. Although in honesty I wasn't trying to reinvent what he was doing, just fix the issue he was having and tell him why it was happening.

Comment: @Yura this answer solves my problem as well. Thank you guys you were very helpful

Comment: Yes but there can be only one answer accepted! But no worries, I don't mind you switched answers, Yura deserves it. His answer is more elegant. I was only trying to show you what was wrong with the code you wrote and why it didn't work. Life goes on. =]

Comment: @AtheistP3ace your answer was great too, and gave me a good lesson :)

Comment: @AtheistP3ace, I will also upvote your answer to make your day brighter :)

Comment: @Yura I am still having problems with this. 
What I want is to have a readonly input on page and on click it turns into normal input. I managed to do that but have some problems. When I click on readonly button it turns into editable input but does not save the value. Here is fiddlejs example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bdefuz8h/

Comment: That is because `text()` method will only work on elements that display the text within them. You've got wrong reference to the value `value="' + value + '"` - basically you're setting old value, and thus it is always empty. So, with an input, remove `.text($input.val())` and use `$input.val()` to set the value to the new input. Also use `.val()` to set the readonly-input just as well. Also use `placeholder` for placeholder text. Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuraji/j5t34rn6/

Comment: Also, if that is always `input`, this whole code may be much simpler, there's no reason to create new instance of the element and replace them with each other. You might not even need javascript at all, and just be happy with `:focus` css styling: https://jsfiddle.net/yuraji/ku3fzamL/

Comment: what if the H2 is used instead of P? @Yura

Comment: Should be pretty straightforward to use any tag

Comment: If anyone need it, I port this answer from jQuery to vanilla JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62830395/1248177

Answer (score 4):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7jz510hg/1/

The issue was by not defining the inputIdWithHash and elementValue variables with var they became global variables.

```
var inputIdWithHash
var elementValue
```

Then since they had global scope the old values of them were available to the document click handler. You want them locally scoped within that turnTextIntoInputField function.

And an update maintaining values: https://jsfiddle.net/7jz510hg/2/

Side note, you are using jQuery 1.6 so I had to use unbind function instead of off.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7jz510hg/3/

This uses latest jquery, event namespacing so we can attach more than one click event to the document therefore allowing us to click between the fields and not lose anything. The previous fiddle would mess up if you clicked directly on fields instead of click field, click document, click field.

Comment: When I click away the text returns to its original value.

Comment: Yea sorry I was just looking at the issue he stated in question that he was loosing and mixing them up. I'll update fiddle to handle values. One sec.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace thank you worked like a charm ! Just what I needed :) I would be very grateful if you could update your fiddle so the value does not return to its original value.

Comment: @zachu Updated answer

Comment: what if the H2 is used instead of P tag? @AtheistP3ace

Answer (score 4):

I port Yura's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33268255/1248177) from JQuery to Vanilla JavaScript if anyone need it. Also this one will work with p, h1, h2, span, whatever:

```js
function editData(e) {
  const el = e.target;
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("value", el.textContent);
  el.replaceWith(input);

  const save = function() {
    const previous = document.createElement(el.tagName.toLowerCase());
    previous.onclick = editData;
    previous.textContent = input.value;
    input.replaceWith(previous);
  };

  /**
    We're defining the callback with `once`, because we know that
    the element will be gone just after that, and we don't want 
    any callbacks leftovers take memory. 
    Next time `p` turns into `input` this single callback 
    will be applied again.
  */
  input.addEventListener('blur', save, {
    once: true,
  });
  input.focus();
}

for (const child of document.querySelectorAll('[data-editable]')) {
  child.onclick = editData;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-editable>First h1</h1>

<p data-editable>First Element</p>
  
<p data-editable>Second Element</p>
  
<p>Not editable</p>
```

Related:

- [JS equivalent for jQuery one()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312249/js-equivalent-for-jquery-one)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, don't make this complicated. I changed the text to the input field with a simple hide and show method. This is very easy to implement and understand.

```js
 $('#editable').on('click',function(){
     var groupname = $("#editable").html();
     $("#editable").css({'display':"none"});
     $("#inputgroupname").css({'display':'block'});
     $("#inputgroupname").focus();
      $("#inputgroupname").val(groupname);
});

$("#inputgroupname").focusout(function(){
   $('#editable').html($("#inputgroupname").val());
  $("#inputgroupname").css({'display':'none'});
  $("#editable").css({'display':"block","margin-top":"2px"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="box-title" style="margin-top:2px; margin-left:5px;" id="editable">Hello</h3>
 <input type="text"  id="inputgroupname" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#tbl').on('click','.editable',function() {

  var t = $(this);          
  var input = $('<input>').attr('class', 'savable').val( t.text() );
  t.replaceWith( input ); 
  input.focus();

});

$('#tbl').on('blur','.savable',function() {

  var input = $(this);      
  var t = $('<span>').attr('class', 'editable').text( input.val() );
  input.replaceWith( t ); 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yp8bt6s0/