# How to convert clicked element into a textarea and back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on [this JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GeJkU/1674/) found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it) I am basically trying to achieve the same, however, my element isn't a `div` or could not just be a `<p>` tag, could be basically be any element while the code below presume it will be a `<p>` tag

How can i make it so that it gets back to its original element?

HTML

```
<p>If no background color...</p>
<span>Element shortcut method for ...</span>
<i>Element shortcut method which ...</i>
```

JS

```
    $(".modal-body div *").on("click", function(){
          divClicked();
    });
    function divClicked() {
        var divHtml = $(this).html();
        var editableText = $("<textarea />");
        editableText.val(divHtml);
        $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
        editableText.focus();
        // setup the blur event for this new textarea
        editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
    }

    function editableTextBlurred() {
        var html = $(this).val();
        var viewableText = $("<p>"); <-- Could have been another tag
        viewableText.html(html);
        $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
        // setup the click event for this new div
        viewableText.click(divClicked);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use contenteditable="true" for your div?

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: well because I did not know we could set that attribute