# How do I tell if a user is contentEditing for contentEditable elements

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a bunch of elements. If you click on a element, it highlights it so you can do stuff. If you click the Delete/Backspace key while a element is highlighted, the element is removed. However I don't want it to delete the element if I'm currently editing the element via contentEditable.

I thought of:

```js
element.oninput = function(){editing = true};
element.onchange = function(){editing = false};
```

but if they start with a backspace/delete it will delete the element before `editing` is set to true.

Demo problem:

```js
let host = document.getElementById("host");
let elems = 0;
let addElem = function(){
    elems++;
    let elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.id = "ElemId"+elems;
    elem.style.border = "black solid 1px";
    elem.innerHTML = "Edit Me...";
    elem.onclick = function(){
        if(selectedElem && selectedElem.id !== this.id) selectedElem.onblur();
        selectedElem = this;
        this.focus();
        this.style.border = "blue solid 5px";
        this.contentEditable = true;
    }
    elem.onblur = function(){
        if(selectedElem.id === this.id) selectedElem = null;
        this.style.border = "black solid 1px";
        this.contentEditable = false;
    }
    host.appendChild(elem);
}
addElem();
addElem();
document.getElementById("add").onclick = addElem;
let selectedElem = null;
host.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.key.toLowerCase() === "delete" || e.key.toLowerCase() === "backspace"){
        if(selectedElem){
            selectedElem.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.item{
background-color:grey; 
font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id = "host">
  <p>Click an element. It now is <span style="border: blue 2px solid;">highlighted</span>. if you click <span class="item">Delete</span> or <span class="item">Backspace</span>, it's supposed to delete the item. (This is functional).<br>Click again after it's highlighted and it allows you to edit it. <span style="font-weight:bold;">While editing</span> it's not supposed to be able to delete.</p>
    <button id="add">Add Item:</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div contenteditable="true">Anything inside this div will be editable!</div>`
i hope this answers your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it

Comment: It can't be a textarea for a lot more complicated reasons. It'd mean a large re-write or removal of editing it.

and I already know about `contenteditable` Try the snippet.

Comment: I think you are over complicating, just to save a delete button.  you have a single event `focus` on which you are trying to do two different actions.

Comment: Nobody told you to use `textarea`, You don't need to copy the example.. just take an idea from the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want it to delete the element if I'm currently editing the
> element via contentEditable.

If I understand correctly, you can define that event with `document`, not with the `contenteditable`.

You can catch the target element while the buttons are pressed via `e.target` property.

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("elem");

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.target !== elem && 
     (e.key.toLowerCase() === "delete" || e.key.toLowerCase() === "backspace")) {
    elem.remove();
  }
};
```

```html
<div id = "host" style="display:inline">
  <span>Item:</span>
  <div id="elem" style="border:black solid 1px;" contenteditable="true">Edit Me...</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```js
elem.style.border = "black solid 1px";
elem.innerHTML = "Edit Me...";
elem.onclick = function(){
    this.focus();
    this.style.border = "blue solid 5px";
    this.contentEditable = true;
}
elem.onblur = function(){
    this.style.border = "black solid 1px";
    this.contentEditable = false;
    host.classList.remove("editing");
}
elem.onkeydown = function () {
    host.classList.add("editing");
};
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (elem.getAttribute("contentEditable") && !host.classList.contains("editing") &&
  (e.key.toLowerCase() === "delete" || e.key.toLowerCase() === "backspace")) {
    elem.remove();
  }
};
```

```html
<div id = "host" style="display:inline">
  <span>Item:</span>
  <div id="elem">Edit Me...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: well it's not that simple, cuz I do want to still be able to delete the element. I've updated the snippet to show the extra step. Because there is a phase where it's highlighted but not editing. As soon as you un-focus it, it no longer becomes editable. I only *don't* want  to delete it when I'm editing it.

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer So, what's wrong with my code? Deleting when losing focus as you said.

Comment: Well I have multible elements. I only want to delete the element when It's focused and not being edited.

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer You mean: Delete the contenteditable when it's empty (doesn't contain any character), right?

Comment: I accidently sumbitted an edit to your post not mine :facepalm:

Comment: Anyways, I've updated the snippet more. Basically I have several elements. When you click one it's now focused. And it allows you to content-edit AND delete. So if I click delete now I want it to delete. However, if I don't click delete and I click again, I'm now editing it. I don't want to delete it if I'm editing it and click the backspace bttn.

Try the demo. You have to click an elem before it allows you to delete it, how ever I can't figure out how to block it from deleting if you click again and start editing.

Comment: -> "Delete the contenteditable when it's empty"... no, In my actual code I just reset it to it's default content.

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer I've updated my answer. I can only think about it.

Comment: Yea I thought about that, I posted it already. Problem is then the user can't begin w/ a backspace/delete.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Frustrated programmer, I just made few small changes to your code.

1. I added a click event listener to document(to capture all key press) instead of host div.
2. another thing I did is introduced class addition and removal to elements and based on class name deciding whether to delete the element or not.
3. Also you set content editable only when this div was already clicked previously else treat this click as first click.

hope this explanation helps!

```js
let host = document.getElementById("host");
let elems = 0;
let addElem = function() {
  elems++;
  let elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.id = "ElemId" + elems;
  elem.classList.add('normal');
  elem.innerHTML = "Edit Me...";
  elem.onclick = function() {
    if (selectedElem && selectedElem.id !== this.id) selectedElem.onblur();
    selectedElem = this;
    if (this.classList.contains('highlightDiv')) {
      this.contentEditable = true;
      this.focus();
    } else {
      this.classList.add('highlightDiv');
      this.classList.remove('normal');
      this.contentEditable = false;
    }
  }
  elem.onblur = function() {
    //if(selectedElem.id === this.id) selectedElem = null;      
    this.classList.remove('highlightDiv');
    this.classList.add('normal');
    this.contentEditable = false;
  }
  host.appendChild(elem);
}
addElem();
addElem();
document.getElementById("add").onclick = addElem;
let selectedElem = null;
//host.onkeydown = deleteText; this is not listening to keyinputs :(
document.onkeydown = deleteText;

function deleteText(e) {
  if (e.key.toLowerCase() === "delete" || e.key.toLowerCase() === "backspace") {
    //debugger; only for debugging in developer tools
    if (selectedElem && selectedElem.contentEditable === 'false' &&
      selectedElem.classList.contains('highlightDiv')) {
      //all criteria met delete the element
      selectedElem.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.item {
  background-color: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.highlightDiv {
  border: blue solid 5px;
}

.normal {
  border: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="host">
  <p>Click an element. It now is <span style="border: blue 2px solid;">highlighted</span>. if you click <span class="item">Delete</span> or <span class="item">Backspace</span>, it's supposed to delete the item. (This is functional).<br>Click again after
    it's highlighted and it allows you to edit it. <span style="font-weight:bold;">While editing</span> it's not supposed to be able to delete.</p>
  <button id="add">Add Item:</button>
</div>
```